# How to read text from UITextInput in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextinput

I am a beginner in swift.
I have

```
class A : UIViewController {
var textInput: UITextInput

init(textInput: UITextInput) {
    self.textInput = textInput
}

func getText() -> String() {
    /// Here I need to get the current text from textInput
}

}
```

How to get it ? Help please. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hi all.. I got finally

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3:

```
let start  = sender.beginningOfDocument
let end = sender.endOfDocument
let range = sender.textRange(from: start, to: end)!

let trimmedText = sender.text(in: range)
sender.replace(range, withText: "new text")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
let start: UITextPosition  = self.textInput.beginningOfDocument
let end: UITextPosition = self.textInput.endOfDocument
let range: UITextRange = textInput!.textRangeFromPosition(start!, toPosition: end!)!
textInput!.textInRange(range!) // for get text
textInput.replaceRange(range!, withText: "some text") // to write text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension UITextInput {
    public var text: String {
        get { text(in: textRange(from: beginningOfDocument, to: endOfDocument)!) ?? "" }
        set(value) { replace(textRange(from: beginningOfDocument, to: endOfDocument)!, withText: value) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `textInput` variable is never declared properly. You might want to consider learning more general practices of Swift before asking specific questions.

Proper declaration of `textInput` would look like:

```
class A : UIViewController {
    var textInput: UITextInput
```

Comment: I am passing a textView or textField to this init(). They were initialising in other controllers. Can you help me how to use a UITextInput ?

Comment: Why not use a `UITextField` and get the text with `textInput.text`?

Comment: Right, why not use a `UITextField`?